# FHIR: .Net Spark : How can I define/ enforce Conformance for an extension and Other resource?

Tags: hl7-fhir

How can I set Conformance so that only certain extensions for a resource are allowed for my server? Same question hold for Other resource where I want to allow only resources my server understand. I looked at Conformance.xml plus Forge tool and could not figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you should avoid rejecting instances that contain unrecognized extensions.  Ignoring them is better practice.  (Unless they're modifierExtensions - those you can't safely ignore if you don't understand them.)  Extensions are the norm in FHIR.  If you start rejecting instances that contain unrecognized extensions, you're going to be unable to interoperate with any system that doesn't specifically design itself to talk to your system (which sort of defeats the purpose of using an interoperability standard).

There is no mechanism at present to indicate that you don't accept unrecognized extensions as part of the Conformance resource, though given that we say you SHALL flag the fact in your Conformance statement, there probably should be.  Can you submit a formal change request for us to add an explicit flag on Conformance?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I'll submit a formal change request. An example will be helpful on how to represent an "Other" resource in Conformance.xml.